# Is there a difference between `parseInt` and `Math.trunc` methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

They both seem to do the exact same thing. (i.e converting float numbers to integers, and work on strings)

I couldn't find any difference, I even asked ChatGPT it said `Math.trunc` can't work on strings which is wrong! it works on numbers and strings.

Comment: Try `Math.trunc("1234hello world")`

Comment: Also using `parseInt()` to convert a number to an integer is not the best idea. Use `Math.floor()`, `Math.round()`, or `Math.trunc()` if you know the source is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, they do fundamentally different operations that often (but not always) produce the same results. `parseInt` is designed to parse a string value into a number. One advantage here is handling other bases (allowing you to express hex or binary strings, not just decimals). Because it assumes your input is a string, it will coerce any input you give it into a string before parsing (even if the value is already numeric). This can have some unexpected side-effects (for example, if the string value of some number would display in scientific notation, you will likely get a much larger or smaller value than you expect).

`Math.trunc`, on the other hand, expects a numeric. It appears to coerce the value you give it (including a string) into a number, then drops everything after the decimal. While in many cases they will produce the same results, there are many where they won't. It is more likely to give you `NaN` (such as when you have odd/unexpected additional characters in the string you pass it), but this may also be a good thing from a user-input validation standpoint.

The correct function will depend on your use case. In general, if you have a string and you know it's base, use `parseInt`. If you just want the integer portion of a decimal number, but that number may be in scientific notation (or you want to know of the string has extraneous characters and fail parsing), `Math.trunc` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are differences between parseInt and Math.trunc methods in JavaScript

```
parseInt("10");      // Output: 10 
Math.trunc(10.9);   // Output: 10
```

Comment: `parseInt(10.9)` returns the same as `Math.trunc(10.9)`. What is the difference that you're expressing?